# best way to stream an API in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, streaming

What is, in your opinion, the best way to stream an API within a loop in a rails app ?

I'm using the Mangopay API to retrieve some datas. It works just fine, but the loading time is huge, because I'm fetching datas in view.

I have a `Payment` model, and each payment got its own Mangopay match.

```
 <% user.payments.each do |p| %>
    <% @payin = MangoPay::PayIn.fetch(p.mangopay_charge_id) %> 
    // doing my stuff with retrieved datas
 <% end %>
```

Obviously, this is super slow, and I was wondering if there was a way to fasten up the process. I looked around, found about streaming, lazyload, and 3 or 4 other viable solutions, but before I get into anything, I thought it might be a good thing to get opinions from more experienced developers.

Comment: "Whats the best way to do X?" or "Is X better than Y?" type questions are off topic for stackoverflow. If you can edit your question to be about a specific problem set instead of a comparison you will avoid downvotes and the question being closed.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: That said you should probably be storing the result of the API request in  your database and never query an external API in the view. Your views should take data from the controller and turn it into HTML in the simplest way possible.

Comment: @max , hmm, I see what you mean, but how can this be done when it come to pure comparisons ? Like, which process is the fastest ? I guess one of the basics of StackOverflow is sharing experience and knowledge, mostly through advices like "You shouldn't do it this way",  which is the first step to "This way is better", which iis basically what I asked.